# How to Change the Scroll Text every time it reaches the bottom

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the text every time the text hits the bottom of the scroll!

I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.
Also, Can someone help me remove the "undefined" from the end of the text?
(i want everything to be automatic, no buttons nor interactivity required please!)
my code is below!

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>

function randomText() {
              //array splashes
              var say = [];
              say[0] = "Welcome.";
             say[1] = "Coming Soon";
  say[2] = "eek";
              //pick a random greeting
              var howmany = 2;
              var bRand = 0;
              bRand = Math.random();
              bRand = Math.floor(bRand * howmany);
              //prepare and docwrite the greeting
              sayWhat = say[bRand];
              document.write(sayWhat)
              document.close()
              //direct type in html p element
              //document.getElementById("splash").innerHTML ='javascript:alert("' + '");'
              // I tried to make this work but it says no.
            }
    
           
 // Change Interval here to test. For eg: 5000 for 5 sec </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  </script>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" as="style" onload="this.rel = 'stylesheet'">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Webpage is Under Maintenance</title>
  </head>
  <body class="red">
    <style media="screen">
      body{
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        margin: 0;
      }
      h1{
        color: white;
      }
      marquee{
        height: 5rem;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .red{
        background: #c60929;
      }
      .green{
        background: #106b03;
      }
      .play{
        background: #ffdd33;
        color: #333333;
      }
      .container{
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      }
      a{
        color: white;
      }
      footer{
        margin-top: 0.5rem;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        padding: 0.5rem;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Site is Under Maintenance</h1>
     <p>
       This Webpage is Currently Under Maintenance.  In other words, We are recoding or changing the code on this website!
       <br>
       <br>
       If we have downloaded javascript or other files to this site.  An Update will be Required after!
       <br>
       In the meantime, Check other Webpages!  This Webpage may be down currently, but there should still be webpages at AstraOnline that are still functioning!
      </p>
      <noscript>
        I see you have Javascript Disabled.   You should try Enabling it, This Site Runs on Javascript!
      </noscript>
      <p>Current state: <span id="status" class="red">Under Maintenance</span></p>
      <marquee direction="down"> <script> document.write(randomText()) </script> </marquee>
    </div>
    <script>
      
      </script>
    <style>
      .simon{
        margin: auto;
        display: flex;
        width: 15rem;
        height: 15rem;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      .simon > button{
        flex: 50%;
        border: 0.25rem solid black;
        appearance: none;
      }
      .simon > button:active{
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
      #r{
        background: #e21b3c;
      }
      #b{
        background: #1368ce;
      }
      #y{
        background: #ffa602;
      }
      #g{
        background: #26890c;
      }
      #alt{
        background: #ffdd33;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        padding: 1rem;
        box-shadow: 0.25rem 0.25rem rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        color: black;
        font-weight: 800;
      }
      #alt a{
        color: black;
      }
    </style>
    ```
````

Comment: `randomText()` doesn't return anything, it does its own writing. What are you expecting `document.write(randomText())` to write?

Comment: So either get rid of the `document.write()` when you call the function, or change the function to return the string instead of writingit.

Comment: for me, i get one of the strings and then undefined.  example: Coming SoonUndefined

Comment: You get one of the strings because it's written inside `randomText()`. Then you get `undefined` because you're writing the return value, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: so how would i make the text scroll without it saying Undefined,  Any other way it gives me absolutly nothing.

Comment: Change `document.write(randomText())` to just `randomText()`

Comment: Okay, Ill try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240403/discussion-between-drake-kologenski-and-barmar).

Comment: You mean change it when you scroll the page? You need to add an event listener for the `scroll` event that changes the message. Note that you can't use `document.write()` after the page is loaded. So you should redefine the function to return the message instead of writing it. Then you can use `document.getElementById("idthatyouaddtomarquee").innerText = randomText();`